# Multiple content backgrounds on a Wordpress site?

Tags: css, web, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know little to nothing about HTML or CSS (but I am trying to learn little by little).
I am currently working on my [professional portfolio](http://frankpernice.com) and I'd like to break the website up a bit better than I have it now now (that is, with horizontal lines after each section). I've designed the website so that it is a one-page style site. However, it would be nice to change the content background for different sections of my resume, the about me (which I know needs more work, I hate talking about myself lol), and the contact me parts of the site. I'm thinking something along [these lines](http://efficientwp.com/), but much simpler.

I'm currently running Wordpress 3.8.1 and using the [Highwind](https://wordpress.org/themes/highwind) theme. I achieved the scrolling action with the [Page 2 Scroll ID](http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-scroll-to-id/) plugin. What you should be aware of is that all the content on the site is on a single page and the menu buttons merely point to different locations on the page by the way of divs. [See this tutorial](http://www.pootlepress.com/2013/02/video-tutorial-a-beginners-guide-on-how-to-create-a-single-page-wordpress-website/) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you're going to be able to get this happening with the Highwind Theme, or at least without some heavy customization of it.

The way the types of sites you're talking about work is that each section of the page has a 100% wide div with a 1255px wide div (the inside div could be anything really as long as it's not 100%) the inner div is centered inside the 100% wide outer div.

Here's a very quick codepen example...
http://codepen.io/catchlightWeb/pen/tpKrG/

For your example, instead of the SectionOuterOne and SectionOuterTwo classes having different colors, they'd have different background images.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So I couldn't make divs around my different content sections?

Comment: Basically, could I just add CSS code to style.css as you provided it and then makde divs around my sections?

Comment: Ah...It did work somewhat. But now I need to get rid of the grey borders on the side. See here:http://i.imgur.com/SaW4ti2.png?1 By the way, I did make a child theme in case you were wondering.

Comment: FYI, I've updated the "along 'these lines'" link as I found another website which better exemplifies what I want. Basically, I'm looking for the functionality that this plugin provides: https://wordpress.org/plugins/genesis-simple-page-sections/screenshots/

Comment: Cool. http://efficientwp.com/ which is a demo site of the example above - featres a thing called parallax Scrolling, in the header section. Other than that it's basically what I outlined on the codepen example - do you know about Chrome DevTools? Right click any element on the page in Chrome and select Inspect Element - this will teach you heaps about HTML/CSS

Comment: If it's a free demo that I can download, I may just switch over to that then; looks very nice. And I use Firefox, but I've used the dev tools in that on occasion. Never in depth. I just wish people would comment their code...nothing worse than trying to interpret someone else's code lol

Comment: I've changed to the Tashan theme; hopefully it'll be better to do what I want. I can't find a free version of efficientwp. I'm just waiting for the theme author to tell me how to create a child theme because he did things a bit differently (there's nothing in the style.css file except comments